# count a particular character in runtime in android

Tags: android

I want to restrict the user to put more than 4 period(.) in a edit text.

how to do this. please any body help

Comment: 4 in a row or 4 in total?  Do you already have a layout with the `EditText` and an `Activity` that can read its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make use of following code.

```
public class Help extends Activity {
public static int count = 0;//use this to check is there are more that 4 '.' char
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            if(count>=4){
                //don't allow to right text
            }

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            //check here if entered text contains more than 4 '.' character

        }



        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}
```

Please check for logic i have not tested

Answer (score 0):

```
Edittext e = (editText)Findviewbyid.....

String t= e.geteditable().gettext(); // check methods
if(s.equals(".") || s.equals("..") || s.equals("...")


{
        throw some exception and reset it in the catch block
   }
```

I could understand this from your question. is this what u wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Following script counts all periods, but multiple periods are counted once: `...` = `.`, and preriods at the beginning aren't counted.

```
String text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText)).getText().toString();
if(text.matches("\\.*[^\\.]+\\.+[^\\.]+\\.+[^\\.]+\\.+[^\\.]+\\.+.+")){
    // 4 or more '.', multiple '..' are counted once
}
```